# How can I run my code during waiting user input

Tags: java, console-application, user-input, wait, elapsedtime

I am making a game in Java console. I want to show elapsed time, waiting input from user. I can't run any code waiting input. How can I run my codes during input wait?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new `Thread`, define what it should do and start it.

Docs:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Check docs for java version you need. These are for version 7.

Also I suggest you to get some knowledge about parallel programming and using threads. There are plenty of material on the internet